# AWS CLI Launch Instance Hostname & Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, hostname, amazon-elastic-ip, aws-cli

Is it possible to do the following with AWS EC2? And if so what is the AWS CLI command for it?

1. Launch an instance and bind an Elastic IP at the same time
2. Change the hostname of an instance that is created with from the AWS CLI

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/index.html

Thanks

---

@ EEAA - I did try to associate and EIP after creation but other than doing a sloppy polling or sleep solution you run the risk of the instance being in the pending state, which makes it unable to bind the address to the instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Launch an instance and bind an Elastic IP at the same time

No, not in your `run-instances` call. You'll need to issue a second command using the `associate-address` option, as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/associate-address.html).

> Change the hostname of an instance that is created with from the AWS
>   CLI

No, setting hostname needs to be part of your post-creation instance configuration.

Comment: I've seen some confusion over the need to bind an elastic IP. I believe in the original VPC product a node would not get a public IP unless an Elastic IP was bound.  In the current product you can get a public IP assigned as part of instance creation (ether explicitly or by default based on the subnet configuration), but it is randomly assigned as opposed to the statically assigned Elastic IP.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Seems more of a comment on the question, though, than on my answer. Or not?

Comment: @ EEAA - I did try to associate and EIP after creation but other than doing a sloppy polling or sleep solution you run the risk of the instance being in the pending state, which makes it unable to bind the address to the instance.

Comment: @EEAA Both really -- you said 'no' which is correct but if the poster is operating under the much older product understanding then the answer can be considered 'yes'.

Comment: @Jib what about having the node do the EIP itself as part of bootup?

Comment: @JasonMartin that can work, but I did confirm with Amazon you cannot atomically initiate an instance and bind an EIP.